# Why am I getting Output Element Not Found Even If Element is Present in Matrix?

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, linear-search

Following Code gives output `Found` if element is present in first row.
When I tried to search element which is present in remaining rows, the output is `Not Found`. Please help me to solve this problem.

**Session**

```
Enter size
rows:2

columns:2
1 2 3 4

Enter Target:3
1       2
3       4

Not Found
```

**Expected Output**

```
Found
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Search(int n, int m, int matrix[][n], int target) {
    int i, j;
    while (i < m) {
        j = 0;
        while (j < n) {
            if (target == matrix[i][j]) {
                printf("Found");
                return;
            }
            j++;    
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nNot Found");
}

void main() {
    int matrix[5][5];
    int rows, col, target;
    printf("Enter size\nrows:");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("\ncolumns:");
    scanf("%d", &col);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    
    printf("\nEnter Target:");
    scanf("%d", &target);
    
    Search(col, rows, matrix, target);
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 Still getting same Output

Comment: dimensions of matrix

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including the exact text of all the input, the observed output, and the output expected instead. Show the complete source code, including the `#include <stdio.h>` that is missing from the code currently in the question. Also change `void main()` to `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- the index variable `i` must be initialized to `0` before the start of the outer loop of the `Search` function. It is less error prone to use `for` loops for this instead of `while` loops.
- The output posted for the session is not consistent with the posted code. The matrix contents is shown but there is no code to produce this output.
- The prototype for `main` should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or equivalent. `void` is not a proper return type for this function.
- The matrix passed to `Search` has a size of 5 rows and 5 columns, but you tell the function a different size: 2 rows and 2 columns, passed as arguments and the C99 prototype tells the compiler that the number of columns is `n` with a value of `2`. This is causing the problem. You should either define `Search` as `void Search(int n, int m, int matrix[][5], int target)` or define `matrix` with the proper sizes.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Search(int n, int m, int matrix[][n], int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (target == matrix[i][j]) {
                printf("Found\n");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Not Found\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int rows, cols, target;

    printf("Enter size\nrows: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &rows) != 1 || rows <= 0)
        return 1;

    printf("\ncolumns: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &cols) != 1 || cols <= 0)
        return 1;

    int matrix[rows][cols];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]) != 1)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    
    printf("\nEnter Target:");
    if (scanf("%d", &target) != 1)
        return 1;

    Search(cols, rows, matrix, target);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GaneshDeshmukh: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.